# Dygraphs: How to use both range-selector and manual zooming

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

If the range-selector is set to true, the manual zooming with the mouse is off. I would like to have both. Is it possible to use both range-selector and manual zooming with the mouse with the dygraphs library? How does this work?

Regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you set the `showRangeSelector` option, it changes the interaction model for the main chart so that drag=pan. If you don't want this, you can reset it to the default (drag=zoom) explicitly:

```
new Dygraph(div, data, {
    showRangeSelector: true,
    interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel
});
```

Here's a [full fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/7640/).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @danvk. Thanks for sharing soution. can you see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521905/set-one-showrangeselector-for-two-dygraph thanks in advanc